# What's the best way to install two versions of python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, installation, homebrew, anaconda

I want a easy and clean installation, in case a need to uninstall in future.

I'm running Sierra on my mac, currently I have a Anaconda 2.4 (with python 2.7) and now I need to use python 3.5 too. I looked to quite a few answers and the process seemed a little tricky to un-do if necessary.

Please, if possible, post also the uninstall process. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use virtualenv?

Comment: I'm currently using this option, but I'm facing some issues with setup. I call python and terminal only calls 3.5.1 or system, even though I change in pyenv global. It must be something to do with bash_profile misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don't let the long answer intimidate you, the process can be resumed to 6 lines (really), but I tried to write the answer that I was looking for.

The option that suit me the best is `virtualenv`.

## Installation

The simplest way is using brew:

```
brew install pyenv pyenv-virtualenv pyenv-virtualenvwrapper
```

to check the list of python versions we can use the command:

```
pyenv install -l
```

since I am interested in 3.5.1, I can easily install with the same command

```
pyenv install 3.5.1
```

## Setup

Once installed, we can check the result using

```
$ pyenv versions
 * system
  3.5.1 (set by /Users/macbookpro/.pyenv/version)
```

this command list all versions installed, and indicates that I'm currently using system's version.

Before we change to 3.5.1 version we need to add pyenv path to .bash_profile.

In the file .bash_profile :

add the following lines. Pay attention if the `PATH` variable is the same in your case.

```
#added for pyenv
export PATH="/Users/macbookpro/.pyenv:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

So now we have everything setup, let's test it

First, we check which version is currently in use:

```
$ pyenv versions
* system
  3.5.1 (set by /Users/macbookpro/.pyenv/version)
```

Ok, now we know we have to change to 3.5.1. We can do it using:

```
$ pyenv global 3.5.1
$ python

Python 3.5.1 (default, Oct 20 2016, 21:43:48) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

We also verified that this is actually working. We now test the system version too.

```
$ pyenv global system
$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/macbookpro/.pyenv/version)
  3.5.1

$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep  5 2016, 20:55:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Everything is working fine.

## Uninstall

Simply :

```
$ rm -fr ~/.pyenv
```

And remove all the .bash_profile stuff that we added in setup.

## Extras

For the Anaconda folk.

In jupyter :

```
   In [1]: import sys
           sys.version
   Out [1]: '2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)]'
```

Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `virtualenv`. It allows you to keep different working versions of python on the same machine without interfering with each other.

**EDIT:**

These are the instructions on how to install `virtualenv` on Mac OS.

Install the latest python version on your system:

`brew install python` (or python3)

Then using `pip`:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Then in your home directory edit the `.bashrc` file. Create it if it doesn't exist. Add this line to the `.bashrc` file:

```
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
```

The line above will make `pip` run only in virtual environment.

Apply the changes:

. .bashrc (if you in your home directory, note the dot and space before `.bashrc` file).

Now you should be able to use `virtualenv`.

If you in your project folder:

```
virtualenv some_venv
```

Then activate it:

```
. ./some_venv/bin/activate (note the dot).
```

Then you can install everything you need using `pip`. All the packages will go to the `some_venv` directory.

You want to deactivate the `virtualenv`, then run `deactivate`.

If you want to delete all the installed packages when you were under `virutalenv`, then just delete `some_venv`. That's it.

Regarding the `pyenv`. Honestly I have never used it. But there is an easy to follow tutorial on the `github` page of the project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, Agreed that pyenv looks the best, please post a complete answer with Install > Setup and Uninstall, so I can mark as right.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that : python already comes pre installed, pip doesn't, also mac uses bash_profile instead of bashrc. I think that this also a good approach for future reference